# Convert short form days of the week to day names in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some short form day names like so:

```
M -> Monday
T -> Tuesday
W -> Wednesday
R -> Thursday
F -> Friday
S -> Saturday
U -> Sunday
```

How can I convert an xml element like `<days>MRF</days>` into the long version `<long-days>Monday,Thursday,Friday</long-days>` using xslt?

**Update from comments**

> Days will not be repeated

Comment: @StevenWilkins: Can days be repeated?

Comment: @Alejandro - Days will not be repeated.

Comment: You need to tell us whether this is XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. Problems like this area always easier in 2.0.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a solution that has none of the shortcomings of @Alejandro 's solution as noted by Dr. Kay (@Michael-Kay).

Comment: Added an XSLT 2.0 solution, too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:d="day"
 exclude-result-prefixes="d">
    <d:d l="M" n="Monday"/>
    <d:d l="T" n="Tuesday"/>
    <d:d l="W" n="Wednesday"/>
    <d:d l="R" n="Thursday"/>
    <d:d l="F" n="Friday"/>
    <d:d l="S" n="Saturday"/>
    <d:d l="U" n="Sunday"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDays" select="document('')/*/d:d"/>
    <xsl:template match="days">
        <long-days>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="$vDays[contains(current(),@l)]"/>
        </long-days>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="d:d">
        <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<days>MRF</days>
```

Output:

```
<long-days>Monday,Thursday,Friday</long-days>
```

**Edit**: For those who wander, retaining the sequence order:

```
<xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="current()"/>
<xsl:apply-templates
         select="$vDays[contains($vCurrent,@l)]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring-before($vCurrent,@l)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Note**: Because **days wouldn't be repeated**, this is the same as looking up for item existence in sequence with empty string separator.

Comment: Nice !  I like the way you define a kind of associative array (l,n).  That's the nice thing about SO.  You get to see better solutions than your own.

Comment: I really don't like solutions that depend on document(''). If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can put the lookup-table in a proper global variable. With 1.0, it's more efficient in most cases to make the lookup table a separate XML document. Also, unless the amount of data is trivially small, lookup tables should use keys.

Comment: The solution seems to assume that the order of the letters in the input is immaterial, which wasn't stated as part of the requirement.

Comment: @Michael Kay: The answer doesn't depend on `document('')`. It has just inline **structure XML data**, that could be properly accommodate to the use case (external source, XSLT 2.0 variable). The answer use a a second data source to drive the transformation, wich is a better pattern than condicional instructions.

Comment: @Michael Kay: You wrote "order of the letters in the input is immaterial, which wasn't stated as part of the requirement", not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it... (There might be more elegant solutions though... ;-)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/days">
    <long-days>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'M')">Monday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'M'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'T')">Tuesday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'T'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'W')">Wednesday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'W'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'R')">Thursday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'R'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'F')">Friday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'F'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'S')">Saturday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'S'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains(.,'U')">Sunday<xsl:if test="string-length(substring-before(.,'U'))=string-length(.)-1">,</xsl:if></xsl:if>
    </long-days>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include the example I gave in the original question please? Or do I just need to include all the days of the week?

Comment: Is that OK (added the commas).

Comment: It's close, given USM the commas are misplaced MondaySaturday,Sunday,  I'll have to look if that order of days is guaranteed

Comment: Why not add the commas unconditionally, put the result in a variable, and then strip the final unwanted comma?

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted solution always displays the long days names in chronological order and in addition, it doesn't display repeating (with same code) days.

**Suppose we have the following XML document**:

```
<days>STMSU</days>
```

**I. This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <my:days>
  <M>Monday</M>
  <T>Tuesday</T>
  <W>Wednesday</W>
  <R>Thursday</R>
  <F>Friday</F>
  <S>Saturday</S>
  <U>Sunday</U>
 </my:days>

 <xsl:key name="kLongByShort" match="my:days/*"
  use="name()"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vstylesheet"
   select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:template match="days">
  <long-days>
   <xsl:call-template name="expand"/>
  </long-days>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="expand">
  <xsl:param name="pcodeString" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="$pcodeString">
    <xsl:variable name="vchar" select=
    "substring($pcodeString,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$vstylesheet">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(key('kLongByShort',$vchar),
             substring(',',1,string-length($pcodeString)-1)
            )
     "/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:call-template name="expand">
     <xsl:with-param name="pcodeString" select=
      "substring($pcodeString,2)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the above document, produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<long-days>Saturday,Tuesday,Monday,Saturday,Sunday</long-days>
```

**II. This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vshortCodes" as="xs:integer+"
 select="string-to-codepoints('MTWRFSU')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vlongDays" as="xs:string+"
 select="'Monday','Tuesday','Wenesday','Thursday',
         'Friday','Saturday','Sunday'
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="days">
  <long-days>
    <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints(.)">
      <xsl:value-of separator="" select=
      "for $pos in position() ne last()
        return
         ($vlongDays[index-of($vshortCodes,current())],
          ','[$pos])
      "/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </long-days>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document**:

```
<days>STMSU</days>
```

**produce the wanted, correct result**:

```
<long-days>Saturday,Tuesday,Monday,Saturday,Sunday</long-days>
```